# Spark - Kafka offset management while eror scenario

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, rdd, offset

I am new to Sacla. I would like to handle the streaming offset transaction  while reading message from Kafka and writing to Cassandra DB. After every write I am committing offset to Kafka. if any error while DB write ,, I need to skip the Kafka offset write.

How to skip Kafka Offset write while DB error ?

**CODE**

```
   kafkaStream.foreach(rdd=> {
      rdd.foreachRDD(conRec=> {
        val offsetRanges = conRec.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
        conRec.foreach(str=> {
          try {
            CassandraHelper.saveItemEvent(str.value())
          }catch {
            case ex: Exception => {
              println(ex.getMessage)
            }
          }
        })
        rdd.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
      })
    })
```

Comment: Suggestion: Kafka Connect has a Cassandra connector that saves offsets for you in case of error

Comment: if any error occurred while saving then what id your scenario ? do you want to continue streaming?  if so, you misunderstood the kakfa use. what is the plan for error message ? kafka is just queue. using group id your consumer read and once you offset the message then it will point to next message in the queue. if you want to skip the commit, it is violation of kafka rule.

Comment: It is depend on whether you want to continue if error happen or not

Comment: @cricket_007 ; please share me any sample code

Comment: @sai pradeep kumar kotha I don't want to commit the error record to Kafka.

Comment: There is no "sample code". Search "Kafka Connect"

Answer (score 0):

so here is a little toy example you could do

```
val ds = spark.createDataset(1 to 1000)
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
//simulates intermittent failure
def writeToCassandra(i:Int):Either[List[String], Unit] = if(i % 11 == 0) Left(List(s"fail $i")) else Right(())
//in stream rdd
//read offset
val succeded = ds.rdd.map(writeToCassandra).reduce {
  case (Right(_), Right(_)) => Right(())
  case (Right(_), Left(err)) => Left(err)
  case (Left(err), Right(_)) => Left(err)
  case (Left(err1), Left(err2)) => Left(err1 ::: err2)
}

succeded match {
  case Right(_) => //commit offsets
  case Left(errList) => // log errors and clean up messages by e.g. writing them to an err topic and then commiting offsets or whatever you want
}
```

just be careful with what you put in your error type (Left of Ether) because of network IO on reduce. Also this will not abort on first failure but rather write with best effort (write everything possible but be aware of failed writes)

EDIT:
After thinking about it a bit I'd probably do it like this

```
val succeded = ds.rdd.mapPartitions(
    partition => {
      List(
        partition.foldLeft[Either[List[String],Unit]](Right(()))(
          (either, entry) => either match {
            case Right(()) => writeToCassandra(entry)
            case Left(errs) => Left(errs)
          }
        )
      ).iterator
    }
  )

val overall = succeded.reduce {
  case (Right(_), Right(_)) => Right(())
  case (Right(_), Left(err)) => Left(err)
  case (Left(err), Right(_)) => Left(err)
  case (Left(err1), Left(err2)) => Left(err1 ::: err2)
}

println(overall)
```

This should only collect the first error per partition and writes partition wise record by record as long as it doesn't fail. might be slower but won't blow up error stacks and stops writing if it encounters the first error.

If you don't care about that you could also limit the number of error messages in the combiner / reduces